# Use ControlMaster socket on bastion

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a host that once full configured has no ingress. On a bastion, I setup a SSH tunnel with ControlMaster prior to the host removing ingress access.

Can I SSH directly to the no-ingress Host using the ControlMaster socket on the bastion? I use ProxyJump to setup the connection, it translates to `exec ssh -W 'host' bastion`

`|****|
| me |
|****|
  |
 ssh -M (socket not found)
  |
  \/
|*********|                |*******|
| bastion | --- ssh -M --> | host  |
|*********|                |*******|`

Comment: No, but you can connect _indirectly_, which is what the Bastion is there for.  That said, the "no-ingress" host _must_ allow ingress from the bastion.

Comment: after setup, it has no ingress. ControlMaster bypasses this by connecting before setup. It does appear ProxyCommand runs on the client and not the server, so it can't use the ControlMaster on the server.

Comment: This works... but isn't the same `ssh bastion ssh -M ... host`